# Submitting Data, Error: Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

Tags: laravel

```
<form action="upload_creation" method="post">
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</div>
</form>
```

this is my code for form, i want to submit a file with button

```
public function upload_creation(Request $request){
    $input = $request->all();
    $creation = $this->creationRepository->create($input);
    foreach($request->file('direktori_gambar') as $image)
        {
            $name=time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move(public_path().'/public/img', $name);
            $input['pictureName']=$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $input['pictureFile']='/public/img/'.$name;
            $mediaUkm = $this->creationPictRepository->create($input);   
        }     
    return view('webgallery.desktugas')->with($this->data);
```

this is the controller i referred to in form Action

after i click the submit button, it came up as no message error on laravel

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: what is route ?

Comment: What does your routes file look like?

Comment: You can't refer to a controller action from your form,  you need to define a route that will map a url and request type to a controller and action.

Answer (score 0):

this is your route in `web.php` locatated in `routes/` folder.

first create route in web.php

web.php

```
Route::post('upload-creation', 'CreationController@newCreation')->name('upload-creation');
```

And in form use route name to give action on file submit

```
<form action="{{route('upload-creation')}}" method="post">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which method do you use in your `<form>` in your template?

If the route is `post()` (like it is in your routes) then you also need `POST` as method in your form.

If you have POST as method in the `<form>`-Tag, look if you have a hidden-input-field called _method.

More details here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#form-method-spoofing

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a hidden input to your form to include your csrf token.

**Laravel 5.6, 5.7**

```
<form action="upload_creation" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

For reference visit the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf).

For older versions of laravel, the syntax is slightly different:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

use enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag 
example:

also don't forget to add {{ csrf_field() }}

Answer (score 0):

you can use Form Helper using Laravel Collectives

Begin by installing this package through Composer. Run the following from the Terminal:

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.2.0"
```

Next, add your new provider to the providers' array of config/app.php:

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Opening & Closing Form

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => route('upload-creation')]) }}

 // default method is post, you can change by adding **method** key

{{ Form::close() }}
```

it will automatically generate the @csrf code which will be hidden but will be available during request submission